# Compare two lists in .Net and action depending on which lists items are in

Tags: .net, extension-methods, ienumerable

I have a web page that saves a list of changes, so in the save action I have two lists, one with the new values and one with the existing ones.

I want to:

- Loop through both lists, unioned and deduped.
- Where in the new list and not in the existing list I want to add a new item.
- Where in both lists I want to skip it.
- Where in the existing list but not in the new I want to delete the item.

It's easy enough to knock up a method to do this, something like:

```
public static IEnumerable<UnionCompared<T>> UnionCompare<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> compare, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    // Create hash sets to check which collection the element is in
    var f = new HashSet<T>(first, comparer);
    var s = new HashSet<T>(compare, comparer);

    // Use Union as it dedupes
    var combined = first.Union(compare, comparer);
    foreach (var c in combined)
    {
        // Create a type that has the item and a flag for which collection it's in
        var retval = new UnionCompared<T>
        {
            Item = c,
            InFirst = f.Contains(c),
            InCompare = s.Contains(c)
        };

        yield return retval;
    }
}
```

However, this rather feels like reinventing the wheel. Is there something out there that already does this? This seems like a problem that somebody else has already solved.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your type T has a unique key (string or id) then i would suggest extracting all keys, put them in a *List* of type *string* or *int* and use the [Intersect and Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) extension methods to fetch the duplicates/missing/new items or write an [IEqualityComprer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408.aspx)-Implementation for your custom type **T** and use again the *List* extension methods.

At the end i think this solution will take more or less the same amount of code as your implementation. I just always try to use what the framework already offers. :-)

Comment: Yes, I could do something like `var newItems = first.Except(second); var removedItems = second.Except(first);` Still seems to be two loops rather than one (and I suspect still two `HashSet`s under the covers for the comparison) but it's a step in the right direction :)

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement!